# How to integrate MongoDB and Rapidminer?

Tags: mongodb, rapidminer

I am using a mongojdbcdriver-0.0.2-javadoc.jar driver to extend mongodb with rapidminer. It really doesn't works. The driver added to jdbc_properties.xml is not getting listed in the rapidminer studio edition.

Could anyone please help on this ?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely this happens because mongojdbcdriver-0.0.2-javadoc.jar does not contain the driver. Please use mongojdbcdriver-0.0.2.jar instead.